# Access to single box account

Tags: box

I am using below code:

```
BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection(dev_token);
```

I am the user who will be using my app and not other users. So the app will interact with single box account. Do i still need Oath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Box developer tokens for this use case. You can also use the [App User authentication model for this use case](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-users).